# Tableau calculated field - Fixed or Exclude

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Here is everything in the Rows: Patient ID, Date of Service, Medication Name, Disease Name, Grant ID.

Patient ID is identical. One patient may have multiple diseases and for every single disease it's possible that there are more than one grant, i.e, multiple Grant IDs.

I want to know: if a patient has more than 1 disease fund on the same DOS and having the same medication.

Here are my thoughts:
{ FIXED [Patient ID], [Date of Service], [Medication Name]: COUNTD ([Disease Name])}
or
{ Exclude [Grant ID]: COUNTD (Disease Name])}

I don't think either gives the correct answer. Need some help!